# Nested IF statements on Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, nested

I'm trying to code the following on excel:

- if x is >=3 and <3.5, return "mild burnout"
- if x is >= 3.5, return "severe burnout"
- if x is <3, return "no burnout"

I have tried this:

```
=IF(AH2>=3,"mild burnout",IF(AH2>3.5,"severe burnout",IF(AH2<3,"no burnout")))
```

However, it does not return "severe burnout" values.

I believe thats because I can't seem to enbed the "and" in this formula.

What i would like to achieve(without success) is:

```
=IF(AH2>=3 AND AH2<3.5,"mild burnout",IF(AH2>=3.5,"severe burnout",IF(AH2<3,"no burnout")))
```

This one does not work

Comment: Check the order of your tests: if the value is 3.5, then it will be true as great than 3 so the reurned value from the if() will be "mild burnout"

Comment: `IF` will stop after first test that returns `TRUE`. So order of comparisons is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=IF(AH2>=3.5,"severe burnout",IF(AH2>=3,"mild burnout",IF(AH2<3,"no burnout")))
```

This way you don't need the extra complication of and()

You can also use a table and vlookup like so to achieve the same result, but it is not an answer to the question about nested if:

[image]

Which has the advantage of being easier to edit and you can extend the categories easily.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=IF(A1<3,"no",IF(A1<3.5,"mild","severe"))&" burnout"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
=IF(AH2<3,"no burnout",IF(AND(AH2>=3,AH2<3.5),"mild burnout",IF(AH2>=3.5,"severe burnout","something else")))
```