# Can I change the value of a cell based on 5 specific values of another cell?

Tags: excel

Not sure if I worded this correctly to be honest. I'm fairly new to excel. I want the value of A3 to change based on the value of A1. There is no formula as these are specific predetermined values.

```
If A1=60, A3 should be 75
If A1=35, A3 should be 98
If A1=12, A3 should be 140
```

I'm wondering if this is possible. Feel free to suggest other answers if this has been asked already. I didn't really know how to word it so I just might not have been able to search for my issue.

Comment: Use if() or a table with vlookup().

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/72529751/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as per my linked answer, same process:

[image]

Nested if(), but needs editing if changes happen.
The table can have the changes and the vlookup will use the new values. If the behaviour needs to change then 0 can be 1 in the vlookup and values of A1 lower than 35 will return 140 etc

Comment: My values do not change whatsoever. That being said the IF nest was exactly what I needed. I didn't know it could be used that way. Thanks a million and a half Mike